# aws-sdk-cpp: how to use CurlHttpClient?

Tags: aws-sdk

I need to make signed requests to AWS ES, but am stuck at the first hurdle in that I cannot seem to be able to use `CurlHttpClient`. Here is my code (`verb`, `path`, and `body` defined elsewhere):

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration;
clientConfiguration.scheme = Aws::Http::Scheme::HTTPS;
clientConfiguration.region = Aws::Region::US_EAST_1;

auto client = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::Http::CurlHttpClient>(ALLOCATION_TAG, clientConfiguration);

Aws::Http::URI uri;       
uri.SetScheme(Aws::Http::Scheme::HTTPS);     
uri.SetAuthority(ELASTIC_SEARCH_DOMAIN);     
uri.SetPath(path);

Aws::Http::Standard::StandardHttpRequest req(uri, verb);
req.AddContentBody(body);

auto res = client->MakeRequest(req);

Aws::Http::HttpResponseCode resCode = res->GetResponseCode();     
if (resCode == Aws::Http::HttpResponseCode::OK) {
  Aws::IOStream &body = res->GetResponseBody();
  rejoiceAndBeMerry();
}
else {
  gotoPanicStations();
}
```

When executed, the code throws a `bad_function_call` deep from within the sdk mixed up with a lot of shared_ptr this and allocate that. My guess is that I am just using the SDK wrong, but I've been unable to find any examples that use the `CurlHttpClient` directly such as I need to do here.

How can I use `CurlHttpClient`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the HTTP client directly, but the supplied wrappers with the `aws-cpp-sdk-es` package. Like previous answer(s), I would recommend evaluating the test cases shipped with the library to see how the original authors intended to implement the API (at least until the documents catch-up).

> How can I use `CurlHttpClient`?

Your on the right track with managed shared resources and helper functions. Just need to create a static factory/client to reference. Here's a generic example.

```cpp
using namespace Aws::Client;
using namespace Aws::Http;

static std::shared_ptr<HttpClientFactory> MyClientFactory; // My not be needed
static std::shared_ptr<HttpClient> MyHttpClient;

// ... jump ahead to method body ...

ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration;
MyHttpClient = CreateHttpClient(clientConfiguration);
Aws::String uri("https://example.org");
std::shared_ptr<HttpRequest> req(
               CreateHttpRequest(uri,
                                 verb, // i.e. HttpMethod::HTTP_POST
                                 Utils::Stream::DefaultResponseStreamFactoryMethod));
req.AddContentBody(body); //<= remember `body' should be `std::shared_ptr<Aws::IOStream>',
                          //   and can be created with `Aws::MakeShared<Aws::StringStream>("")';
req.SetContentLength(body_size);
req.SetContentType(body_content_type);
std::shared_ptr<HttpResponse> res = MyHttpClient->MakeRequest(*req);
HttpResponseCode resCode = res->GetResponseCode();     
if (resCode == HttpResponseCode::OK) {
  Aws::StringStream resBody;
  resBody << res->GetResponseBody().rdbuf();
  rejoiceAndBeMerry();
} else {
  gotoPanicStations();
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly for a string but how would you do this for a file? I am not able to upload a file with a stream. A file is created on S3 but sadly with 0 Bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same error when trying to download from S3 using `CurlHttpClient`.

I fixed it by instead modelling my code after the integration test found in the cpp sdk:

```
aws-sdk-cpp/aws-cpp-sdk-s3-integration-tests/BucketAndObjectOperationTest.cpp
```

Search for the test called  `TestObjectOperationsWithPresignedUrls`.